# Sometime Sql Connection Error from windows forms-Network related instance error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sql-server-2012

Sometimes following error happening in windows application. The error is like

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I am having more than 50 forms in my application and most of the times there is no error. But sometimes, there is an error like this and when I am trying to connect sql its works fine.

Comment: Do you use one class for the connection or do you put the connection string and method in multiple forms ?

Comment: Either you're using the wrong connection details in one particular place and that's where the error is occurring or else you just have intermittent network or server issues.  When the error actually occurs, do some proper debugging to find out which.  You'll know exactly where in your code it occurred.  You certainly should do, anyway.

Comment: @Thryn, I am using one class for connection.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, Normally it's not happening in the development side..we tried to reproduce it. But I can't..But client getting at least 2 times in a day and I can see the error from the error log.

Comment: That's why you should be logging all your exceptions.  There are various .NET logging components that will write to files or even email directly to you, which is what we do in my office with log4net or NLog.  For Windows apps, it may be just as easy to roll your own but those are particularly useful for web apps.